# Correct calculation of a model's inference time

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

The following snippet from my code is where the training and evaluation take place:

```
def run(dataset, model, runs, epochs, lr, weight_decay, device, patience, permute_masks=None):
    val_losses, accs, durations, stopped_epochs = [], [], [], []
   
    for i in range(1, runs + 1):

        data = data.to(device)
        model.to(device).reset_parameters()
       
        optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=weight_decay)
        
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            torch.cuda.synchronize()

        t_start = time.perf_counter()
        
        best_val_loss = float('inf')
        test_acc = 0
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=patience, verbose=True)
        infer_time = 0

        for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
          
            train(model, optimizer, data)

            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
            infer_time_start = time.perf_counter()
            eval_info, accuracy_class = evaluate(model, data)
            infer_time_end = time.perf_counter()
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                torch.cuda.synchronize()

            if eval_info['val_loss'] < best_val_loss:
                best_val_loss = eval_info['val_loss']
                test_acc = eval_info['test_acc']
         
            infer_time += (infer_time_end - infer_time_start)
           
            early_stopping(eval_info['val_loss'], model)
        
            if early_stopping.early_stop:
                print("Early stopping... Num of epochs:", epoch)
                stopped_epochs.append(epoch)
                break

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
        t_end = time.perf_counter()
        
        val_losses.append(best_val_loss)
        accs.append(test_acc)
        durations.append(t_end - t_start)

    loss, acc, duration, infer_duration = tensor(val_losses), tensor(accs), 
                                          tensor(durations), (infer_time/epochs)

    return loss, acc, duration, stopped_epochs, infer_duration
```

There are two types of duration being calculated in my code. `duration` refers to the whole time of training and inference time whereas `infer_duration` only refers to the inference time. Is my code calculating the model's inference time correctly?

Comment: You should skip the first few batches as those are usually slower than they normal. And take average of each batch instead.

Comment: Obviously different batch size will give different speed. So it depends on what do you measure this for.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen What do you refer to by "batch"? as I am not using batch in my approach. I have "runs" and "epochs"